# Codepen into elementor

Tags: javascript, elementor, codepen

I wanted to place this codepen project https://codepen.io/pizza3/pen/JjKjbZY into an htlm widget in elementor, but I couldnt get it working no matter what I tried, anyone could help me for this ?

Nothing is displayed in the htlm widget when I insert the code in the script tag
this is a part of the javascript that I can't get working into elementor :

```
import { EffectComposer } from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.120.0/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js";
import { RenderPass } from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.120.0/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js";
import { UnrealBloomPass } from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.120.0/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.120.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

var scene,
  camera,
  renderer,
  width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight,
  controls,
  bloomPass,
  composer,
  material;
```